# Use ICollection instead of List

Tags: c#, ilist, icollection

I have an external method which returns `List<IPAddress>`

I write in my class other method which is a wrapper for that. But I was told to not return `List<>`,but `IList` or `ICollection`.
For now what I have :

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
List<IPAddress> addr = obj.GetAddr();//GetAddr() now return `List`,but should be changed to return ILIst or ICollection
```

What should I do - casting?

**Upd**
I did what you said and get an errr "can`t implicitly convert Ilst to List
(It is .net 4.5)

Comment: What's wrong with returning a generic list? And might I suggest you rename `GetAddr()`? There's no need to abbreviate, and the function name makes it sound like it returns a single object instead of a collection.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you'll actually benefit from returning one of those interfaces instead of a `List`.  It is only removing potentially useful functionality for your caller, and it's highly unlikely to help the implementation of that method itself.

Comment: The current conventions are to program to interfaces, so you return interfaces, and let the consumer determine how they want to use the results. Maybe it works better as an array for the people using your method instead of a List. Programming to interfaces gives the consumer that freedom.

Answer (score 2):

What he/she probably meant is: return the list *as* an `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`.

In order to do that, simply change your method's signature and return the list as you normally would:

```
public ICollection<T> Method(){
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    List<IPAddress> addr = obj.GetAddr();

    return addr;
}
```

This is to avoid binding your client's to a concrete `List<T>` implementation.

By returning something more abstract, like an `ICollection<T>`, or even an `IEnumerable<T>`, you won't run into any problems if you later decide to use a `HashSet<T>` instead of a `List<T>` internally. The signature and the client's code will remain the same.

Comment: @Yakov post your actual code, and the error message exactly as it is

Answer (score 1):

You can change the method return type to `IList<IPAddress>` or `IEnumerable<IPAddress>` like:

```
public IList<IPAddress> GetAddress()
{
    return new List<IPAddress>(); //replace with your code to return list
}

public IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetAddress()
{
    return new List<IPAddress>(); //replace with your code to return list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the return value of the method.  Since `List` is implicitly convertible to both interfaces, there is no need for any cast.

Answer (score 0):

If `obj.GetAddr()` returns `IList<IPAddress>`, `ICollection<IPAddress>`, or `IEnumerable<IPAddress>`, all you need to do is add `.ToList()` to the end of your assignment:

```
List<IPAddress> addr = obj.GetAddr().ToList();
```

Or, you can follow the current convention of not explicitly typing your variables, and just do the following:

```
var addr = obj.GetAddr();
```

This will then allow you to maintain your `addr` variable as whatever return type your `GetAddr()` method returns. You will still have access to all the properties of that return type.

Comment: He wants to change it to return an `IList` instead of a list, not to return a `List` instead of an `IList`.

Comment: The code that he's showing is not the `GetAddr()` method. It's consuming the results of the method in his `addr` variable. There is a comment after that line where the OP discusses how to change his code with the new interface return of the method.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware the he hasn't show the implementation of the method.  I read the comment. It specifically says that he's need to change that method so that it returns an `IList` *instead* of what it's currently returning, which is a `List`.  He did *not* say that it currently returns an `IList` and that he needs a `List`.

Comment: The "what should I do - casting?" makes me believe that he's trying to consume that result cause it's currently giving him an "unable to convert" error between the method result and the object he's trying to assign it to. Either way, the question isn't well written.

Comment: He has not said that he is getting an error at all, and he very specifically said that he is currently returning a list but he was told he should instead be returning an `IList` or `ICollection`.  It's a very specific statement, and this answer is contrary to it.